# Find if any of values in group is in certain values in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to see if any elements within a grouped variable is in a set of values.

Either a SAS or PROC SQL solution will work.

Here's a sample dataset:

```
data input;/*table name*/
length ID 3 var1 $8;/*define char length*/
input ID var1 $;/*$ signifies char*/
datalines;/*start data*/
1 A
1 A
1 B
2 A
2 A
2 A
;/*end data*/
run;

ID  var1
1   A
1   A
1   B
2   A
2   A
2   A
```

I want to see if any of the values in `var1` within each group `ID` equal "B" or "C". If one of them is either "B" or "C", then I want the output table to equal 1, else 0. In this example, because group ID = 1 has a "B" in `var1`, the output of `var2` would be equal to 1. For group ID = 2, `var2` should equal 0.

In R, I would use `any()` and this would be fairly straightforward. I know SAS has a similar function in SAS IML, but I'm not sure it can be used the same way. I'm looking for a relatively simple way to do this that avoids the use of `do` loops or subqueries.

Here's the desired output:

```
data output;/*table name*/
input ID var2;/*$ signifies char*/
datalines;/*start data*/
1 1
2 0
;/*end data*/
run;

ID  var2
1   1
2   0
```

I've found a few resources that are similar, but haven't found anything that hits directly on this question.

[Similar SQL Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784786/how-to-check-if-value-exists-in-each-group-after-group-by)

[Similar SAS Community Question 1](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Find-if-a-group-contains-a-value-to-create-new-variable-SAS-9-4/td-p/423771)

[Similar SAS Community Question 2](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Order-of-columns-create-data-set/td-p/789892)

[SAS IML any()/all() Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374804/does-sas-have-a-equivalent-function-to-all-or-any-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few different concepts here:

- Use FIRST to set the flag to 0 at the beginning of each ID.
- Use IN to check for the list of values.
- Use RETAIN to keep the value as it loops down the column.
- Use Last to output the flag at the last record of each ID.

```
data output;
set input;
by ID;
if first.ID then var2=0;
retain var2;
if var1 in ('B', 'C') then var2=1;
if last.ID then output;
drop var1;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and does what I asked. I edited the table and var names to match my question.

Answer (score 2):

SAS evaluates boolean expressions to 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE).  So the MAX() over the group will indicate if ANY of them are TRUE.

```
data input;
  length ID 8 var1 $1 ;
  input ID var1 ;
datalines;
1 A
1 A
1 B
2 A
2 A
2 A
;

proc sql noprint;
create table want as
  select id
       , max( var1 in ('B' 'C') ) as var2
  from input
  group by id
;
quit;

proc print;
run;
```

PS: The risk involved in only keeping 3 of the 8 bytes needed to store numeric values is not worth any miniscule disk space saved.  But for character variables you could save a lot of space by defining the length only as long as needed since character variables could be up to 32,767 bytes long. Also there is no value to adding the $ in the INPUT statement after the variable has already been defined as character. Once a variable's type has been defined you cannot change it anyway.